# Camel and Spring Integration

Tags: apache-camel, spring-integration

I want to test camel spring integration example from the apache camel site 
http://camel.apache.org/springintegration.html but I am getting the exception
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel outputchannel.

my short code is given below:

```
<channel id="inChannel"/>
<channel id="outputChannel"/>

<beans:bean id="greeting" class="com.javarticles.spring.integration.Greeting"/>

<service-activator input-channel="inChannel" ref="greeting"   method="sayHello" output-channel="outputChannel"/>

<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:activemqsource"/>
        <to uri="log:input"/>
        <to uri="spring-integration:inChannel? inputChannel=outputChannel"/>
        <to uri="log:output"/>
    </route>
```

I tried to search related problems but I did not get with camel could any one tell me how to subscribe the outputchannel

Answer (score 0):

According to the Camel documentation mentioned by you, the config should be like this:

```
 <to uri="spring-integration:inputChannel?inOut=true&amp;inputChannel=outputChannel"/>
```

Your issue is `inOut=true`:

> The exchange pattern that the Spring integration endpoint should use. If inOut=true then a reply channel is expected, either from the Spring Integration Message header or configured on the endpoint.

Comment: @Bilan thanks for your reply. But as far as I understand the option inputChannel=outputChannel in the spring-integration consumer endpoint is used to receive the reply from the service-activator. If that is not correct how can I define the reply channel. could you give me example please

Comment: ??? I don't understand what you don't understand. I just show you what Camel tutorial provides. And according their words you exactly should use `inputChannel=outputChannel` to expect reply from the `service-activator`. And you really need `inOut=true`, because I know nothing about Camel, unless those words in the Tutorial.

Comment: <to uri="spring-integration:inputChannel?inOut=true&amp;inputChannel=outputChannel"/> it was same error.